# Why are location and try_files directives required for default configuration in nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, configuration

I am running Nginx 1.10.3 on Debian 9.0.

This is how my default nginx configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` looks (most of the comments removed for clarity).

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

My document root contains just one file for the default home page.

```
$ ls -l /var/www/html/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 867 Jun 13 02:34 index.nginx-debian.html
```

With this setup, I get the expected responses, i.e. the home page loads
successfully and trying to access anything else leads to `HTTP 404`.

```
$ sudo systemctl reload nginx
$ curl -I http://localhost/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 04:47:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 867
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 21:04:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "593f01f2-363"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

$ curl -I http://localhost/foo
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 04:47:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive

$ curl -I http://localhost/foo/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 04:47:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
```

Now I remove the location configuration from the default configuration.
Now my configuration looks like this without the location configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

With this setup, I still get similar responses.

```
$ sudo systemctl reload nginx
$ curl -I http://localhost/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 04:54:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 867
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 21:04:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "593f01f2-363"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

$ curl -I http://localhost/foo
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 04:54:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive

$ curl -I http://localhost/foo/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 04:54:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
```

My questions:

1. What is the usefulness of the `location` and `try_files` directives in this case?
2. Can you specify a situation where a configuration like this with `location` and `try_files` directives would produce different results than a configuration without these two directives?

Comment: The second parameter of the `try_files` statement is not implemented by default. But otherwise, this is just a template. You can also remove the `index` and `server_name` directives if you want, as they also have reasonable defaults.

Comment: @RichardSmith What do you mean by the second parameter of `try_files`? The `$uri/` parameter? If it is not implemented by default, then why does the output in the second example look similar to the one in the first example?

Comment: It tests for the presence of a directory, so the directory called `foo` needs to exist.